# Is there a way to have a Xamarin.Mac app hide its window?

Tags: xamarin.mac

Is there a way to have a Xamarin.Mac app hide its window?

In Main.storyboard I see the `<window>` element has attribute `visibleAtLaunch=“NO”` set, so maybe there is some code making it visible in the first place I could suppress.

Comment: https://medium.com/@venj/hide-window-instead-of-close-it-when-clicks-the-close-button-25768e41ee2d?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to add this to the default ViewController:

```
        public override void ViewDidAppear()
        {
            base.ViewDidAppear();

            this.View.Window.Close();
        }
```